# Compile Qt 5.3 without SSE2 support

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make qt library compatible with  AMD processors with SSE only, but without SSE2,  compiling with MSVC2013,  so I am configuring qt 5.3 with

```
configure -prefix c:\qt\qt5.3-sse -opensource -nomake tests -no-sse2 -platform win32-msvc2013
```

and adding `-arch:SSE` option to `CFLAGS`  in *qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013* . However building of *qjpegd.lib* fails with unresolved external `qt_convert_rgb888_to_rgb32_ssse3`

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /DLL /OUT:..\..\..\..\plugin\imageformats\qjpegd.dll @C:\Users\msbuild\AppData\Local\Temp\nm8C62.tmp

qjpeghandler.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__dec
spec(dllimport) void __fastcall qt_convert_rgb888_to_rgb32_ssse3(unsigned int *
unsigned char const *,int)" (__imp_?qt_convert_rgb888_to_rgb32_ssse3@@YIXPAIPBE
@Z) в функции "public: __thiscall QJpegHandler::QJpegHandler(void)" (??0QJpegHa
dler@@QAE@XZ)
..\..\..\..\plugins\imageformats\qjpegd.dll : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенны
внешних элементов: 1
```

Comment: +1, but please paste English error output next time. It is clear in this case, but could not be confusing in other cases.

Comment: `./configure --help` tells : "-no-sse2 ........... Do not compile with use of SSE2 instructions.", but the linker error says that it misses some sse3 function used in jpeg lib